# Issue with playing embedded video within UIWebview in a UINavigationController stack (IOS7)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uinavigationcontroller, embedded-video

Just run into this strange problem. I have a UIViewController which contains a webview loading in a website with the standard loadRequest method. Some of the pages have embedded videos which work fine when the page is displayed by itself. However, things go wrong when I push the page with a web view into a UINavigationController

Embeded YouTube videos will try to open the movie player controller full screen for a split second but then immediately close. Videos that are hosted on the site I'm loading open in the full screen controller and play fine except the pause button doesn't work. However when I close the movie controller the web view is completely black.

This only happens when I have the view inside a navigation controller. Seems the UIWebViews private UIMoviePlayer doesn't like being part of the navigation stack.

Has anyone had this issue? And better still, figured out a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it in the end. If anyone has the same problem, I was populating a webview created as a subview of a UIViewController in a navigation controller all done via storyboards. I kept the view controller created via the storyboard but created the webview in it programatically and that fixed the issue.